# Algorithm to iteratively fill right side of visual bar chart

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I currently have this, which outputs a bar chart iteratively on the left side.

```js
const arr = [6,10,4,5,1];
let c = 10;
let r;  
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    r = "";
    r += "| ";
    for (let k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        if (arr[k] == c) r += " __";
        else if (arr[k] < c) r += "   ";
        else r += "|  ";
    }
    console.log(r);
    c--;
}
```

I would like to modify this so that it also outputs the right hand of the bar chart like so

```
|     __         
|    |  |         
|    |  |         
|    |  |         
|  __|  |         
| |  |  |   __   
| |  |  |__|  |   
| |  |  |  |  |   
| |  |  |  |  |   
| |  |  |  |  |__
| |  |  |  |  |  |
```

So, I tried adding this under the first if() statement
`else if (k < arr.length - 1 && arr[k + 1] < c && arr[k] > c) r += "|  |";`. This adds the right `|` at the correct places however it shifts all the other characters after it.

Therefore, my question is how can I work around this? Is there an algorithm to follow to ensure it doesn't shift over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [6,10,4,5,1, -1];
let c = 10;
let r;  
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    r = "";
    r += "| ";
    for (let k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {       
        if(k > 0 && arr[k-1] > arr[k] && arr[k] == c) r += "|__";
        else if (arr[k] == c) r += " __";
        else if(k > 0 && arr[k-1] > arr[k] && arr[k-1] > c) r += "|  ";
        else if (arr[k] < c) r += "   ";
        else r += "|  ";
    }
    console.log(r);
    c--;
}
```

What about this? It is just hardcoded in conditions.